# Are translates of Gaussians an overcomplete set in $L^2(\Bbb R)$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces

Consider the Gaussian $\exp(-t^2/2)$. Is it the case that any function in $L^2(\Bbb R)$ can be written as a limit of a sum of scalings and translations of Gaussians? That is, for any $f\in L^2(\Bbb R)$, is it the case that

$$f(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n\exp(-(t-t_n)^2/2),$$

where $a_n\in\Bbb C$ and $t_n\in\Bbb R$ and the convergence is understood in the $L^2$ sense? Via the Fourier transform, we can view this as asking if any function $g$ in $L^2(\Bbb R)$ can be written in the form

$$g(\omega) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\exp(-i\omega t_n)\exp(-\omega^2/2).$$

It seems to me that this encroaches a bit on frame theory but I haven't had much exposure to it so I can't quite see how to show this is true or not.

If this is indeed the case, could we even extend this to all Schwartz space functions since they have a lot in common with the Gaussian?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Do this for, say, continuous functions on $[-R, R]$ using Stone-Weierstrass and then send $R \to \infty$.

Comment: @Qiaochu: As defined, I don't think these functions form an algebra. (Note that we are not allowed to horizontally scale the Gaussian.)

Comment: Oh, bother. ${}$

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a certain topic in quantum mechanics: namely, the _coherent states representation_ (composed of Gaussians and all complex translations of them), which form an overcomplete basis of $L^2(\mathcal{R})$. I'm having a hard time finding a good mathematical (i.e. not physics-centric) reference, unfortunately, but that's something you might try to trace.

Comment: @Semiclassical appropriate username. I thought about this as well and it's closely related but not quite. I was doing some searching to this effect earlier but all I got was a bunch of physics mumbo jumbo. At one point I would have labeled myself a physicist but those days are well behind me and I'm not a fan of math as interpreted by physicists so I stopped reading up on coherent states. Maybe if I find something I'll update my post.

Comment: Aye, that's the risk of the physics literature on this. I may try to put together an answer that at least clarifies (for readers stumbling upon these comments) what coherent states are and why I 'm bringing them up.

Comment: Coherent states are mathematically related to wavelet transforms; see Grossmann and Morlet 1984, or a book on wavelets (I think Daubechies, perhaps)

Comment: @icurays: Thanks for the suggestion. Is there a linkage between that and Wiener's Tauberian theorem mentioned below? That'd clarify the 'related but not identical' status of coherent states in relation to this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this follows from [Wiener's Tauberian theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener's_tauberian_theorem), the $L^2$ case.

Since the answer is short, I'll keep the old version below the cut. It was based on misreading of the question (RBF allow horizontal scaling).

---

Yes, this is true. Key terms: *radial basis function*, *universal approximation property*.

A classical reference (with a proof of more general result) is *[Universal Approximation Using Radial-Basis-Function Networks](http://www.ise.ncsu.edu/fangroup/ie789.dir/Park.pdf)* by J. Park  and I. W. Sandberg.

Comment: I've heard of that theorem but I never knew what it was. Thanks for this!